# Change DIV position on click and animate jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to move a `DIV`with animation from center to left, and by default `DIV` on click in `jQuery`, where parent div is with `position:relative`, what I was thinking is, onclick the parent `DIV` position will be changed from relative to absolute and then run animate function, but it's not working, it's just shifting from center to left on click, no animation.

Here is the code which I am trying:

```
$("#bx1 > .column-wrapper-inner > a ").click(function(){
    $(".custom-col-md-2").css({position: "absolute"});
    $(".column-wrapper").css({position: "absolute"}).animate({left: '50px'}, "slow");
 });
```

**Note:** I want to change the div position from relative to absolute only on click not by default, as by default elements are in grid.

Can any one please help with this!

**UPDATE** : Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyw0du72/1/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your html and css as well? Or make a fiddle with them :)

Comment: Sorry missed it, will add it now

Comment: I think you should not change the position. It should remain absolute and the center could be achieved by pre-calculating the centered position.

Comment: added the jSFiddle

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What should animate and what not?

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/qyw0du72/2/ ?

Comment: @Pugazh I am looking to move main div (grey color) from center to left with animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this (comments in code)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bx1 > .column-wrapper-inner > a ").click(function() {
    var col = $(".custom-col-md-2.column-wrapper-main"); // set the col
    col
      .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': '50%',
        'margin-left': -(col.outerWidth() / 2) + 'px'   // margin left to move box back into middle
      })                                                // set the css so that it stays centered but has absolute positioning
      .animate({
        'left': '50px',
        'margin-left': '0'
      });                                               // animate to the left

  });
});
```

```css
.custom-col-md-2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

.column-wrapper-inner {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-col-md-2 column-wrapper-main">
  <div class="column-wrapper animated infinite slideInUp" id="bx1">
    <div class="column-wrapper-inner">
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <h1>Title goes here</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Desceription goes here.</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-wrapper-hov"></div>
</div>
```